# cannot transform (struct containing pointer) type to a *bsonx.Document

Tags: mongodb, go, mongo-go

I've recently started using the official mongo-go-driver (github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver) and it seems that I cannot use pointers in my structs -> ex.:

```
type example struct {
  hello *string
}
```

If you initialize this struct and try to insert it to the database, you get the error:

```
"Failed to insert doc: cannot transform type example to a *bsonx.Document"
```

Diving deeper into the library, I find this error:

```
"StringEncodeValue can only process string, but got a *string"
```

Does this mean that pointers can not be used at all? If so, does anyone know why pointers would not be supported?

Using a different type produces the same result.
Example error when using an integer type:

```
"IntEncodeValue can only process int8, int16, int32, int64, int, but got a *int"
```

Comment: No, it means *string pointers* cannot be used at all. String pointers are pretty unusual anyway, since strings are immutable.

Comment: It's not just strings. I see string pointers fairly often in Go code when nil values are wanted. In any case the same issue occurs when using other data types. I've updated my question with the result of using a pointer to an integer value.